# Perl Reg ex matching problem $trailer =~/00fd00.*00fc00/;

Tags: perl, regex

I'm trying to extract the characters: `328c1e460b000a2020202020200000`
from a string: `01e000000fd00328c1e460b000a202020202020000000fc00434f4`

I'm using Perl on Windows XP and have tried:

```
$trailer =~/00fd00.*00fc00/;
$trailer =~/00fd00\w+00fc00/;
```

for example:

```
$trailer ="01e000000fd00328c1e460b000a202020202020000000fc00434f4";
print"Original  $trailer\n";

#$trailer =~/00fd00.*00fc00/;
$trailer =~/00fd00\w+00fc00/;

print "Final     $trailer\n";
```

The output is:

```
Original  01e000000fd00328c1e460b000a202020202020000000fc00434f4
Final     01e000000fd00328c1e460b000a202020202020000000fc00434f4
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like:

```
$trailer =~ s/.*00fd00(.*)00fc00.*/$1/;
```

A plain match will not alter the variable itself, you need a substitution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [regex captures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Capture-buffers):-

```
my $trailer ="01e000000fd00328c1e460b000a202020202020000000fc00434f4";
my ($trailer_extract) = $trailer =~/00fd00(\w+)00fc00/;

print "Original  $trailer\n";
print "Final     $trailer_extract\n";
```

This has the advantage over substitutions of leaving $trailer intact if you still need to reference the non-extracted string elsewhere in your code.